# QML skip item on ListView when using arrow keys

Tags: listview, qml

I am using `ListView` and want to skip a particular item when using  navigating the list using the arrow keys.

For example, there are 4 elements in `ListModel`.

```
ListModel {
    id: myListModel
    ListElement {
        item_name: "Item 1"
        item_description: "Description 1"
    }
    ListElement {
        item_name: "Item 2"
        item_description: "Description 2"
    }
    ListElement {
        item_name: "Item 3"
        item_description: "Description 3"
    }
    ListElement {
        item_name: "Item 4"
        item_description: "Description 4"
    }
}
```

I want "Item 3" to always be skipped when the user navigates with the 'Up' or 'Down' key.

For example, when  'Item 4' is selected and the user pushes 'Up' key, the selection should jump from  "Item 4" to "Item 2". Similarly, if "Item 2" is selected and then the 'Down' key is pressed, then "Item 4" should become selected ("Item 3" should be skipped)

I've coded the delegate below, but it does not operate as I expected:

```
// delegate
Component {
    id: myComponent
    Item {
        width: 40; height: 40
        enabled: (ListView.view.currentIndex === 2) false : true
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: item_name
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the delegate's `enabled=false` does not work as I expected; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the 4-way part of this question? If you navigate 2 items at a time with the up and down key, how do you go down by 1 item, for example?

Comment: You've already written the comment, and those are correct directions. Just  available 'Up' and 'Down' for example.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of a `ListView` that has keyboard focus is to navigate up and down by one item, as you may know. So, you need to override that behaviour using the attached properties of [`Keys`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: myListModel
        ListElement {
            item_name: "Item 1"
            item_description: "Description 1"
        }
        ListElement {
            item_name: "Item 2"
            item_description: "Description 2"
        }
        ListElement {
            item_name: "Item 3"
            item_description: "Description 3"
        }
        ListElement {
            item_name: "Item 4"
            item_description: "Description 4"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: 40
        height: 80
        focus: true
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: myListModel
        currentIndex: 0
        delegate: Item {
            id: delegateItem
            width: 40; height: 40
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: item_name
                color: delegateItem.ListView.isCurrentItem ? "red" : "black"
            }
        }

        Keys.onDownPressed: {
            if (listView.currentIndex + 2 < listView.count - 1)
                listView.currentIndex += 2;
        }
        Keys.onUpPressed: {
            if (listView.currentIndex - 2 >= 0)
                listView.currentIndex -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

You haven't specified how the user should navigate one item at a time, but you should be able to figure that out from the above code and the documentation for `Keys`.